# Image Loader Google volley

Tags: android-volley, image-loading

Is it possible to find whether the image is loaded into the Imageview in Google volley .
 I have a ListView that has a ImageView in each list item. And need to show a progress indicator until image is loaded to view in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking also about some kind of progress indicator, but when I tested it volley is so quickly that for small images that has no sense to have any loader - I have more then 1000 items in listview without any problem. I guess that to have progress indicator in each imageView would make more troubbles when scrolling